# How to remove the last comma in a list of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

The list is supposed to get the square of each number. I've managed to do that but I need to remove the last comma in the sequence.

When I use this code:

```
def multiplicator():
      for a in range(3, 20):
          b = (a*a)
          print(b, end=",")

multiplicator()
```

I get:

```
9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your loop and add a condition:

```
def multiplicator():
    for a in range(3, 20):
        b = (a*a)
        print(b, end="")
        if a<19: # if not the last element
          print(end=",") # print ","
    print() # print new line after everything

multiplicator() # => 9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361
```

You can also use a ternary condition to shorten the code:

```
def multiplicator():
    for a in range(3, 20):
        b = (a*a)
        print(b, end="," if a<19 else "")

    print() # print new line after everything
multiplicator() # => 9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but if you look at the other answers you should be able to figure it out all by yourself...just because an answer "works" doesn't automatically make it good.

Comment: @martineau I could've made it better, I know how to use join, I intentionally left the code as-is because I know that the OP is a beginner and wants his code to be as close to his as possible, that's why he accepted my answer and not the others. And this is probably an assignement so they won't even allow him to use join.

Comment: Rather than dumb-down your answers, in the future perhaps you should consider putting both ways in your answer—otherwise it makes it look like your own understanding of the language is also very elementary (which could raise suspicions that the advice you're giving isn't the best). In this particular instance, since the OP accepted your answer, you may actually be hindering OP's understanding of things by making them think they have to do what's in your answer, which is clearly sub-optimal, to accomplish their goal.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str.join` to add a delimiter between strings which will handle not adding an extra one to the end.

```
>>> ','.join(str(a*a) for a in range(3, 20))
'9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def multiplicator():
    print_list = list()
    for a in range(3, 20):
        b = (a*a)
        print_list.append(b)
        print_list.append(',')
    for i in print_list[:-1] :
      print(i, end='')

multiplicator()
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option would be:

```
def multiplicator():
    for a in range(3, 19):
        print(a*a, end=',')  # directly a*a, no need for an intermediate variable
    print(19*19)
```

A generic solution would be:

```
def multiplicator(n):
    for a in range(3, n-1):
        print(a*a, end=',')
    print((n-1)*(n-1))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> multiplicator(20)
9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361
```

**Note:**

This is a simple and similar approach to what you are trying to do, but you should definitely go for [@CoryKramer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141494/4575071) answer using [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 0):

def funcPattern(n):

```
# Base case (When n becomes 0 or negative)
if (n == 0 or n < 0):
    print(n, end=", ")
    return

print(n, end=", ")

# First print decreasing order
funcPattern(n - k)
if (n == m):
    print(n, end=" ")
elif (n != m):
    print(n, end=", ")
```

`n = 10
m = n
k = 2
funcPattern(n)`

Comment: def funcPattern(n):

    # Base case (When n becomes 0 or negative)
    if (n == 0 or n < 0):
        print(n, end=", ")
        return

    print(n, end=", ")

    # First print decreasing order
    funcPattern(n - k)
    if (n == m):
        print(n, end=" ")
    elif (n != m):
        print(n, end=", ")


# Driver Code


n = 10
m = n
k = 2
funcPattern(n)

Answer (score 0):

A one line way of doing it:

```
a = range(3, 20)
print(*[i**2 for i in a], sep=',')
```

The list is created using list comprehension, then the unpacked list (using the * operator) is printed; with ',' being the separator.

Output will be:

```
9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361
```